# Custom Activites in Workflow Foundation dynamic Argument Validation

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I have build a custom activity for Workflow Foundation which works exactly as exprected and I'mno implementing some validation on the arguments.

I have 4 arguments, the first 2 `File_Location`  and `CheckIn`  are required, and the validation `[RequiredArgument]` works fine. Is there a way of making the last 2 arguments `CheckInComment`  and `chekintype`  required if `CheckIn` is true.

```c#
public sealed class File_Upload : CodeActivity
{
    [Category("Input")]
    [DisplayName("Location of file to upload")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> File_Location { get; set; }

    [Category("Input")]
    [DisplayName("Check in file?")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<bool> CheckIn { get; set; }

    [Category("Input")]
    [DisplayName("Check in comment")]
    //Required if CheckIn == True
    public InArgument<string> CheckInComment { get; set; }

    [Category("Input")]
    [DisplayName("Check in type")]
    //Required if CheckIn == True
    public InArgument<CheckinType> chekintype { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        //MY CODE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this exactly.

You could check at runtime though and throw an `ArgumentException` if the conditionally required fields aren't provided.

Another option is to have 2 activities, eg. `File_Upload_WithCheckIn` and `File_Upload_WithoutCheckIn` and only have the required arguments on the first one.